# Two Sum. Difference in return and print

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm doing the famous two sum question from leet code. I noticed, if I wrote:

```
def findpair(num, target):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(num)):
            if num[i] ==num[j]:
                continue
            if num[i] + num[j] == target:
                return(i, j)

mylist = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 , 6]
print(findpair(mylist, 7))
```

It only returns one pair, which is index 0 and 5.
However, if I change `return` to `print`, it will give me all the pair. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because that's how functions work. when you use the `return` keyword the function will stop that's why it is returning a single pair.

a better solution is to create a list and each time the condition is true you append the pair to the list. Then when the loop is finished you return the whole list which contains all the pairs.